# "Brain doping": Can drugs compensate a lack of concentration while learning?

Tags: health, motivation, learning, emotional-responses

I am almost at the end of my bachelor degree but I am afraid that I never will be able to finish this mere rest. Not only because the rest of my degree (around 20 credit points) is downright uninteresting but I feel that I am not mentally capable anymore of saving knowledge related to any exam.

I have read about students compensating such issues with drugs like Methylphenidate (you may know it under its trade label "Ritalin"). I really regard this as an option for one semester just to finish the rest of my degree once and for all. I am currently trying to learn for an rather easy exam but I am not able to save the knowledge, like an emotional self-defense I am mentally distracted all the time.

Can drugs like Ritalin be the solution? I am only remotely aware of the side effects however I feel also despaired enough to pay a high price.

Comment: While this is not on-topic here, I would strongly encourage you to seek out appropriate, trained, licensed medical advice that is customized to you. Many Universities offer counselling centers for students, and I heavily advise you to to seek out such appropriate help. The effect of drugs heavily vary depending on your actual condition. Taking the wrong drugs out of desperation can lead to death, imprisonment, expulsion, or a worsening of symptoms, many of which can be completely hidden from the person taking them until it is too late.

Comment: It is not on topic but I gave you a +1 for this good and reasonable advice. Thank you!

Comment: There are a variety of underlying conditions that can result in difficulty concentrating.  ONE of these is ADHD, which is SOMETIMES treated with a stimulant medication such as Ritalin.  It's important to find out what is really at the bottom of your trouble concentrating.  You could start with a general practitioner, who might or might not want you to see a specialist. // Even if the result of all this is a prescription for a stimulant medication, please note that there are multiple options of drug, dosage, delivery (e.g. short-acting, 8-hour, 12-hour, etc.).  There are a number of possible...

Comment: ...unpleasant side effects, so these are drugs where you definitely want to be working closely with a medical provider with extensive experience with them. // There are behavioral treatments that can help as well -- drugs are not the only option. // Please keep in mind that it is quite common for undergraduates to hit sort of a saturation point in their last semester or their last year.  Maybe it will help you to know that.  However, it is also quite common for young people to find the period immediately post graduation quite challenging too.  Bottom line, this might be a good time to start...

Comment: ...finding out more about yourself -- what makes you tick, what underlying problems can be worked out so that you can find life easier to navigate, and more satisfying, what strengths you can tap into to help you cope with the current and upcoming challenges you are facing.

Comment: Thank you @aparente001 that you invested so much time in providing a really helpful comment. Just one remark concerning "to find the period immediately post graduation quite challenging too". Actually I am already in work life (a bit more than 20 hrs per week) and it is for me a good compensation and backing. Work gave me a lot of confidence in contrast to university because in the work I could prove myself as a creative problem solver and I really could improve my programming skills.

Comment: @BruderLustig - I am very glad to hear it!  Someone close to me graduated in May and has been very affected by difficulties finding a job in his field.  However, he recently received an offer.  It is amazing how much this has improved his state of mind. // It can be helpful to get evaluated and try to find a therapist who is a good match prior to any big transition. // The side effect my younger son had trouble tolerating, when he tried a stimulant medication, was that when it wore off he felt an insatiable hunger, right at bedtime, and this caused weight gain and sleep difficulties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The available evidence certainly supports the view that Methylphenidate/Ritalin boosts cognitive abilities while being somewhat safer than amphetamines. Note that if you are caught in possession of this drug without a prescription you will suffer considerably more than the consequences of the drug itself in most countries.

Personally, I doubt that the boost given by Methylphenidate/Ritalin can be significant enough to make a difference in your grades. Note that it will do absolutely nothing to cure your lack of interest in the topic. If you aren't studying enough hours, you won't make it no matter how hopped up you are.

This probably doesn't help much, but my own strategy as an undergraduate student was to simply neglect studying those topics I was not interested in, and simply take the hit to my grade.

Comment: "Personally, I doubt that the boost given by Methylphenidate/Ritalin can be significant enough to make a difference in your grades." - I don't care about grades, a D grade is enough (a 4 or Genügend as it is called in German speaking regions). but I am afraid that I will not be capable of attaining even this D grade without a little helper.

Comment: @BruderLustig Why don't you just try some coffee? It's legal and has some stimulating effect, though obviously not much compared to amphetamines.

Comment: I drink already a lot of it (4 cups a day) @DepressedDaniel and although my cup of coffee is one of the little joys I have still left it couldn't solve my issues yet.